# Enabling Java 7 on Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, java

The first time I tried to use Java on Mountain Lion, it installed automatically. Unfortunately, it installed Java 6, so I installed Java 7. If I navigate to Java in System Preferences, only Java 7 is listed. How do I switch to Java 7, or remove Java 6?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple's tools don't see Java 7, Oracle's tools don't see Java 6; it's all a bit ugly. Luckily there's an ugly fix to go with it!

Normal Mac Java 6 running on 10.8:

```
java -version
java version "1.6.0_33"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_33-b03-424-11M3720)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.8-b03-424, mixed mode)
```

Install the Java 7 JDK (not just the JRE) [from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1637583.html).

Move the system java out of the way (so you can get it back if you want):

```
sudo mv /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdkx
```

Then symlink 7 in place of 6:

```
sudo ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_06.jdk /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk
```

and voila:

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_06"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_06-b24)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.2-b09, mixed mode)
```

I've not had trouble with any java apps so far (apart from java preferences which checks which java it's running under).

There's probably a better way of doing this, but it works for me.

Comment: I found that I had to open Java Preferences after doing this and drag java7 to the top of the the preferred order dialog which was presented, otherwise java6 was still used

Answer (score 2):

To switch to Java 7 for when Java is run from the terminal, I added the following line to `~/.profile`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_06.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Answer (score 2):

$ cp -r /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_12.jdk /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/

$ sudo ln -sF /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_12.jdk CurrentJDK

$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_12-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_12-ea-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b26, mixed mode)