# How can I keep Java 7 up to date?

Tags: macos, software-update, java

As far as I understood Apple provides only Java 6 for Mountain Lion.

[Here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58116/enabling-java-7-on-mountain-lion) I found how to install and use Java 7.

However I suppose that by installing Oracle Java it will not be update by means of the Mac App Store. How can I be sure that Oracle Java is always up to date, even better automatically (at least with a notification of "ready to update")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not have noticed it, but Oracle Java 7 installs a new item in System Preferences with a feature that automatically checks for updates by default, and prompts you to install them. Thus, this is taken care of.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does it automatically check as it just tells me the Java is out of date and press a button to update now

Comment: @WheatWilliams Does this update the Java Plugin for internet or also the Oracle JDK stored in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`? The utility sais that I have Java 1.7 u9 while `java -version` sais Java 1.7.0_07-b10

Comment: Personally I don't understand the current confusion between Apple's release version of Java and the browser plugin, and the new independent Java release. Things seem to be in a state of flux. Can anyone explain the situation please?

Comment: @user9290 In the old days, Apple received from Oracle a dump of closed source code of their implementation of Java. Apple would add their own code that integrates Java with Mac OS X and then Apple would release. Eventually Apple decided to join the open-source project [*OpenJDK*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) with Oracle & IBM & others, donating their Mac-specific source code. Now every release of OpenJDK is available simultaneously for multiple platforms like Solaris, Linux, Windows, AIX, & macOS. Apple continues to have staff working on Java, but now working in the open via OpenJDK.